# Whole contents are pushed up when using KeyboardAvoidingView in react native

Tags: android, react-native, tpkeyboardavoiding

I have a issue when using KeyboardAvoidingView in react native.
Follow is my code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style = {styles.pagetitle_part}>
        <Text style = {{fontSize: 25, color: '#ffffff'}}> Register User </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style = {{position: 'absolute', top: 30, left: 20}} onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn')}>
            <Image style = {{width: 15, height: 15}} resizeMode = 'contain' source = {require('../assets/images/left_arrow.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style = {styles.main_part}>
        <ScrollView style = {{width: deviceWidth}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator = {false}>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior = 'padding'>
                <View style = {styles.component_input}>
                    <View style = {styles.title_view}>
                        <Text style = {styles.title_text}> Fist Name </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style = {styles.input_view}>
                        <TextInput underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent' style = {styles.input_text} onChangeText = {this.handleFirstName}>{this.state.first_name}</TextInput>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style = {styles.component_input}>
                    <View style = {styles.title_view}>
                        <Text style = {styles.title_text}> Last Name </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style = {styles.input_view}>
                        <TextInput underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent' style = {styles.input_text} onChangeText = {this.handleLastName}>{this.state.last_name}</TextInput>
                    </View>
                </View>
                ... ... ...
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
</View>
```

On Android, when I tap TextInput then upper component is pushed up and so below component is fill out the screen. But on iOS it's Ok.

Follow is screenshot before tapping the TextInput on android:

[image: screenshot before tapping the TextInput]

Follow is screenshot after tapping then TextInput:

[image: screenshot after tapping the TextInput]

As before I said, on iOS, everything is ok.
How can I fix this issue on android?
Why on iOs is different from on android?
I'm very happy to hear your advance. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you're having this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up

Comment: Any update on this issue??

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you should set the "behavior" parameter of the KeyboardAvoidingView to "padding", but not for android. I show a working example in this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52255480/5359812

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have still same issue although dismiss the behavior parameter. As said in my question, the upper component(styles.pagetitle_part) is still pushed up. And screen is filled out by lower component(styles.main_part). I hope your advance.